# Why Eclipse doesn't recognize method from Spring?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, jsp, spring-mvc

I have some `jsp` file with the following line:

```
<form:form action= "${s:mvcUrl('BC#save').build()}" method="post" modelAttribute="book">
```

At `build()` Eclipse complains:

```
The method getBuild() is undefined for the type MvcUriComponentsBuilder.MethodArgumentBuilder
```

But [here's](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/MvcUriComponentsBuilder.MethodArgumentBuilder.html#build--) the doc about `build()`. So if everything is working normally(I've tested all the way and everything worked as planned), how can I tell Eclipse that everything is OK? My goal here is show only real problems, real errors. Is this some wrong configuration?